# Passar valor de variável PHP dentro de laço while para javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Possuo uma variável dentro de um código *php* com um laço while e preciso modificar essa variável `$codigo` dentro do javascript.

Essa variável `$codigo` recebe um número diferente a cada laço de repetição

```
data-toggle='popover1', data-toggle='popover2' ...
```

E esse valor precisa ser incrementado também ao *javascript*

```
 $('[data-toggle='popover1']'), $('[data-toggle='popover2']') ...
```

Segue o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="popover<?php echo $codigo; ?>"]').popover({html: true});   
});
```

```php
<?php
$codigo = 1;
while ($codigo < 10) {
$codigo = $i;
$i++;
?>

<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#Alt'>MODAL</button>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Alt" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p><button id='id_codigo'
type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
data-position="top-left" title="Contato" 
data-toggle="popover<?php echo $codigo; ?>" 
data-placement="down" data-content="Nome: id='id_nome'
<br>Endereço: id='id_endereco'
<br>Contato: id='id_contato' ">Contato</button></p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

[Segue o código online](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7WFE3LUWOPF)

Comment: Explica direito qual o problema está enfrentando, o que você deseja de resultado e qual resultado está acontecendo atualmente.

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta

Comment: Na realidade como essa variável está dentro de um laço de repetição e recebe um incremento a cada repetição, também preciso desse incremento no javascript, ou seja, preciso passar sempre o valor da variável php para o java script dentro desse laço de repetição.

Comment: Não da para fazer isso que você quer, manipular com o *Javascript* variáveis hospedadas em *PHP*. Existe uma distinção de camadas entre cliente(html) e servidor(php).É um ciclo o usuário faz a solicitação de uma página. O servidor inicia um código em *php* e quando **terminarem todas** as atividades em php o servidor devolve ao cliente uma página html e cessa sua atividade. O navegador recebe a página e a renderiza, dependendo das ações do usuário uma nova solicitação é enviada ao servidor. É um ciclo, ora o processamento está no cliente, ora o processamento está no servidor mas nnca nos dois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo o seu modelo você pode fazer algo parecido com isto:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while ($i < 10) {
    $codigo = $i;
    $i++;
    ?>

    <button type='button' title='Sem Contato' data-toggle='popover<?php print $codigo ?>'>Sem Contato</button>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("[data-toggle='popover<?php print $codigo ?>']").popover({html: true});   
    });
    </script>


    <?php
}
?>
```

O que fiz foi adicionar o mesmo `<?php print $codigo ?>` da linha acima. Eu sugiro aninhar isto de outra forma, por exemplo: Imprime todos os botões depois repete o loop imprimindo o JS separado.

Comment: No caso pra passar o valor da variável pro javascript é dessa forma mesmo? Aqui não deu certo

Comment: Isto não passa o valor para o javascript, apenas "escreveu" um javascript, se olhar no código fonte renderizado verá que ficou `data-toggle='popover1'` `data-toggle='popover2'` etc. Para passar uma variável segue o mesmo esquema na declaração da variável `var variavelJS = <?php print $codigo ?>;`. Posta a necessidade do resultado final pra entender o que você quer.

Comment: Realmente preciso do passar o valor da variável em php pro javascript.

Comment: Então ficaria assim? data-toggle='popover´variavelJS´

Comment: Pronto editei a minha pergunta e fiz como eu gostaria que ficasse

Comment: Bom dia Carlos, então, como o @Augusto Vasques disse, são "camadas diferentes", ou seja, você não consegue acessar uma variável do PHP no javascript nem do javascript no PHP. O que dá pra fazer é escrever o código Javascript usando o PHP. E este código que te passei funciona pra isto, você verificou o "código fonte renderizado" ou seja, no navegador? Tem um detalhe ai que tá passando também é a repetição de aspas simples, se você abre aspas simples deve abrir aspas duplas internamente à primeira e assim sequencialmente, e vice-versa.

Comment: No seu "código renderizado" deveria estar assim `$("[data-toggle='popover1']")` e não assim `$('[data-toggle='popover1']')`. Desculpe a pergunta que não precisa de resposta, você é iniciante em programação?! Se for, dá uma atualizada nos seus conceitos javascript e php, só releia alguns livros para fixar/masterizar o que cada um faz, assim você vai perder bem menos tempo com pequenas coisas. Exemplo, isto ai tá te tomando horas, se você ler dois livros, 1 por dia, você vai deixar de perder várias horas em pequenos trechos. Ou seja, a velha frase de algumas horas afiando o machado.

Comment: Isso sou iniciante. Obrigado pela resposta.